# ListView не правильно рисует ячейки, использование процедури updateItem

Tags: listview, javafx, fxml

```
 invoiceListView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<ListViewRow>, ListCell<ListViewRow>>(){
        @Override
        public ListCell<ListViewRow> call(ListView<ListViewRow> param) {
            ListCell<ListViewRow> cell = new ListCell<ListViewRow>(){
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(ListViewRow item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if(!empty){
                        setText(item.getText());
                        pseudoClassStateChanged(item.getPseudoClass(), true);
                    } else {
                        setText(null);
                    }
                }
            };
            return cell;
        }
    });
```

вот описание updateItem. Создание форми с ListView

```
 FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/addItemKind.fxml"));

    Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);
    stage.setTitle("Форма для додавання упаковок");
    Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
    scene.getStylesheets().add("styleAddItemKind.css");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    loader.<AddItemKindController>getController().setInvoiceList(this.invoiceList);
    stage.addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWING, event -> loader.<AddItemKindController>getController().showListView());
    stage.showAndWait();
```

styleAddItemKind.css

```
.list-cell:present{
-fx-background-color: green;
```

}

```
.list-cell:missing{
    -fx-background-color: red;
}

.list-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-selection-bar;
}
```

При загрузке форми список с цветами віглядет корректно. После Scroll начинают появляться ячейки красного цвета, если долго юзать все ячейки становятся красними

Answer (score 0):

Раз вы меняете `pseudoClassStateChanged` на тру для не пустых ячеек, соответственно вам надо проставлять `pseudoClassStateChanged` в false для пустых ячеек.

```
 invoiceListView.setCellFactory(new Callback < ListView < ListViewRow > , ListCell < ListViewRow >> () {
    @Override
    public ListCell < ListViewRow > call(ListView < ListViewRow > param) {
        ListCell < ListViewRow > cell = new ListCell < ListViewRow > () {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(ListViewRow item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (!empty && item != null) {
                    setText(item.getText());
                    pseudoClassStateChanged(item.getPseudoClass(), true);
                } else {
                    setText(null);
                    pseudoClassStateChanged("present", false);
                }
            }
        };
        return cell;
    }
 });
```

Comment: смотрите я добавил pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("present"), false);                 pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("missing"), false); все равно появляются красние ячейки.

Comment: Вам надо удалять тот псевдокласс, который вы проставляли. Если проставляли present, то и изменять должны present. Если это не поможет, попробуйте удалять этот псевдо класс : getPseudoClassStates().remove(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass('present'))

Answer (score 0):

```
invoiceListView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<ListViewRow>, ListCell<ListViewRow>>(){
            @Override
            public ListCell<ListViewRow> call(ListView<ListViewRow> param) {
                ListCell<ListViewRow> cell = new ListCell<ListViewRow>(){
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(ListViewRow item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if(!empty){
                            setText(item.getText());
                            pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("present"), false);
                            pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("missing"), false);
                            pseudoClassStateChanged(item.getPseudoClass(), true);
                        } else {
                            setText(null);
                            pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("present"), false);
                            pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("missing"), false);
                        }
                    }
                };
                return cell;
            }
        });
```